# Better practices reducing modules import size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6, lodash, es6-modules

I am using some libs in my JS application and I have some doubts about best practices in modules import.

I'm using `VSCode` and the extension [Import Cost](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost) so I can see the size of all the imported modules.

I will use `lodash` as an example here:

```
// This is how I usually import the modules
import { isEmpty, isEqual, cloneDeep } from 'lodash' // 69.5K (gzipped: 24.5K)
```

And this is how I noticed that I can reduce the import size:

```
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty' // 6.2K (gzipped: 2.2K)
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual' // 14.7K (gzipped: 4.8K)
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep' // 17K (gzipped: 5.2K)
```

Here we can see a big difference in the size of the imported modules: `69.5K (24.5 gzipped)` vs `37.9K (12.2K gzipped)`

I really like the first option using destructuring assignment, it is pretty simpler and looks a lot better, but thinking about performance and bundles size, how is the best/correct way to do it?

Comment: Probably a bug in the extension, which can't calculate the tree-shaking of the library